# imageMagick not creating exact number of tiles

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am creating an image having dimension 357x357 using imagemagick and then creating 100 tiles using crop command but it only crops first 10 images 
here are the commands

convert -size 357x357 xc:skyblue 1.jpg

convert -crop 10x10@ 1.jpg 1-slices.jpg

first command creates image with 1.jpg having dimension 357x357 and second command is for creating 100 tiles but it only creates 10 tiles and returns.
Here are the tile names it created

1-slices-0.jpg ......... 1-slices-9.jpg

Why it is not generating 100 tiles?

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@` applies the evenly spaced crop along one dimension (apparently). Best thing I can think of is to isolate each plane into a separate `-crop` command

```
convert 1.jpg -crop x10@ -crop 10x@ 1-silces-%d.jpg
```